# Replace NA's in some columns and rows based on a lookup table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns, lookup, na

Replicable dataset below.

Let me set the scene: I have a detection history of 3 species recorded by 5 cameras on concurrent days (V1:V10)(1=detected, 0=undetected).
Cameras 1 and 2 did not record on the first and last days, hence the NAs in columns V1 and V10.
Camera 5 did not record for the first and last two days, hence these NAs.

Because no caracals were recorded by camera 2, and no leopards were recorded by camera 5, these rows are fully populated with NAs.

I know, however, that cameras 2 and 5 did work during this time so there should be "0"s for V2:V9 for caracals at camera 2 and for V3:V8 for leopards at camera 5.

So my question is: how can I populate these cells with 0s rather than NAs?

I need to maintain NAs when the cameras were not working during the first and last days.

My actual dataset has hundreds more species, cameras, and days so I cannot do this manually.

I have been trying to figure this out but have had absolutely no success.
I thought about creating a lookup table of when each camera worked but couldn't figure out the syntax.

Any help is appreciated

```
camera<-c(rep(1:5,each=3))
species_names<-c("baboon","caracal", "leopard")
species<-c(rep(species_names,5))
V1<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,1,1,1,0,NA,NA,NA)
V2<-c(0,1,0,0,NA,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,NA,NA,NA)
V3<-c(1,0,1,0,NA,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,NA)
V4<-c(0,1,1,1,NA,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,NA)
V5<-c(1,1,1,0,NA,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,NA)
V6<-c(1,0,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,NA)
V7<-c(0,0,1,0,NA,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,NA)
V8<-c(1,1,1,1,NA,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,NA)
V9<-c(0,0,1,0,NA,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,NA,NA,NA)
V10<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA)

dataset<-data.frame(camera,species,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10)
dataset

   camera species V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1       1  baboon NA  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  NA
2       1 caracal NA  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  NA
3       1 leopard NA  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  NA
4       2  baboon NA  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  NA
5       2 caracal NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
6       2 leopard NA  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  NA
7       3  baboon  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
8       3 caracal  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
9       3 leopard  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
10      4  baboon  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
11      4 caracal  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
12      4 leopard  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
13      5  baboon NA NA  1  0  1  1  1  0 NA  NA
14      5 caracal NA NA  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  NA
15      5 leopard NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

My dataset should look like this:

```
   camera species V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1       1  baboon NA  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  NA
2       1 caracal NA  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  NA
3       1 leopard NA  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  NA
4       2  baboon NA  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  NA
5       2 caracal NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  NA
6       2 leopard NA  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  NA
7       3  baboon  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
8       3 caracal  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
9       3 leopard  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
10      4  baboon  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
11      4 caracal  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
12      4 leopard  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
13      5  baboon NA NA  1  0  1  1  1  0 NA  NA
14      5 caracal NA NA  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  NA
15      5 leopard NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  NA
```

Comment: Btw it's better to do ``data.frame(camera, species....)`` rather than using ``cbind``, which coerces them to characters first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can go with

```r
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
  group_by(camera) %>% 
  mutate(across(V1:V10, ~ifelse(any(!is.na(.)) & is.na(.), 0, .))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 15 x 12
   camera species    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
    <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1 baboon     NA     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0    NA
 2      1 caracal    NA     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0    NA
 3      1 leopard    NA     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    NA
 4      2 baboon     NA     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0    NA
 5      2 caracal    NA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    NA
 6      2 leopard    NA     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0    NA
 7      3 baboon      0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 8      3 caracal     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
 9      3 leopard     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
10      4 baboon      1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
11      4 caracal     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
12      4 leopard     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
13      5 baboon     NA    NA     1     0     1     1     1     0    NA    NA
14      5 caracal    NA    NA     0     0     0     1     0     0    NA    NA
15      5 leopard    NA    NA     0     0     0     0     0     0    NA    NA
```

The main idea is, if all observations in a column are `NA`, `NA` should be kept, else the `NA` should be replaced by `0`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `across` with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
    mutate(across(V2:V9, ~ifelse(camera==2 & species=="caracal", 0,.)),
           across(V3:V8, ~ifelse(camera==5 & species=="leopard", 0,.))
           )
```

Output:

```
   camera species V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1       1  baboon NA  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  NA
2       1 caracal NA  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  NA
3       1 leopard NA  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  NA
4       2  baboon NA  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  NA
5       2 caracal NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  NA
6       2 leopard NA  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  NA
7       3  baboon  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
8       3 caracal  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
9       3 leopard  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
10      4  baboon  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
11      4 caracal  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
12      4 leopard  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
13      5  baboon NA NA  1  0  1  1  1  0 NA  NA
14      5 caracal NA NA  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  NA
15      5 leopard NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have literally thousands of lines of data so cannot do this row by row

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for the reply. But camera 2 and 5 are those fixed and only the species change?

Answer (score 0):

So here is one way to do this. This uses `tidyverse` functions, so load that library. The basic idea is to first have a long dataset that indicates which days the cameras were working and which they were not.  Like so:

```
camera_data<-data.frame(
  camera=rep(c(1:5),each=10 ),
  Day=rep(paste0("V",1:10), times=5),
  Status=c(0,rep(1,8),0,0, rep(1,8),0, rep(1,20), 0,0, rep(1,6),0,0)
)
```

It will look like this

```
   camera Day Status
1       1  V1      0
2       1  V2      1
3       1  V3      1
4       1  V4      1
5       1  V5      1
6       1  V6      1
7       1  V7      1
8       1  V8      1
9       1  V9      1
10      1 V10      0
11      2  V1      0
```

A `Status` of 1 means the camera is working and 0 means its broken.

Then, you need to pivot your detection data to also be long, like so:

```
dataset_long<-dataset %>% pivot_longer(cols=V1:V10, names_to="Day", values_to="Presence")

> dataset_long
# A tibble: 150 x 4
   camera species Day   Presence
    <int> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
 1      1 baboon  V1          NA
 2      1 baboon  V2           0
 3      1 baboon  V3           1
 4      1 baboon  V4           0
 5      1 baboon  V5           1
 6      1 baboon  V6           1
 7      1 baboon  V7           0
 8      1 baboon  V8           1
 9      1 baboon  V9           0
10      1 baboon  V10         NA
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Now you can simply `left_join` them and use `if_else` in `mutate` to find the `NA`s that should be 0 and replace them:

```
dataset_long<-dataset_long %>% left_join(camera_data) %>%
mutate(Presence= if_else(is.na(Presence) & Status==1, 0, Presence))
```

Finally if you need your data back in wide format, you can use `pivot_wider` to do that and drop the extra `Status` column:

```
dataset_done<-dataset_long %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols=c(camera,species), names_from=Day, values_from=Presence)
```

Your final data is:

```
> dataset_done
# A tibble: 15 x 12
   camera species    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
    <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1 baboon     NA     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0    NA
 2      1 caracal    NA     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0    NA
 3      1 leopard    NA     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    NA
 4      2 baboon     NA     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0    NA
 5      2 caracal    NA     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    NA
 6      2 leopard    NA     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0    NA
 7      3 baboon      0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 8      3 caracal     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
 9      3 leopard     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
10      4 baboon      1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
11      4 caracal     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
12      4 leopard     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
13      5 baboon     NA    NA     1     0     1     1     1     0    NA    NA
14      5 caracal    NA    NA     0     0     0     1     0     0    NA    NA
15      5 leopard    NA    NA     0     0     0     0     0     0    NA    NA
```

As a general rule I find it is much easier to manipulate data in long format than wide format - so pivoting is often a good first step.

This does require you to make the camera_data table, but I don't see any way around that.